# Как правильно масштабировать изображение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, pillow

Есть исходное изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как средствами `python` я могу его масштабировать в :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображение обрезается и становится нужного мне разрешения, обычным `resize` подобного достичь не удалось. Я так понимаю, что мне нужно определить пропорцию, обрезать изображение с помощью `crop` и только потом увеличить. Размер изображения может быть любым, в данном случае оригинал 500х517, сделать надо 1920х1080 или 1080х1920, в зависимости от пользовательского ввода.

```py
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(image_path)
image = image.convert('RGBA')
image = image.resize((1920, 1080))
```

Comment: во-первых, вы не указали критерии изменения изображения; во-вторых, вы не привели свой код в вопросе.

Comment: @strawdog исправил

Comment: Обрезать и потом увеличить, совершенно верно. Можно сначала увеличить, а потом обрезать. Так даже ещё лучше, потому что будет точно нужный размер.

Comment: @Эникейщик, я не очень понимаю как мне правильно все посчитать и обрезать. Можно подсказку?

Comment: Ну если у вас одна сторона 500, а нужно сделать 1920, то во сколько раз надо ее увеличить?

Comment: @Эникейщик в 1920/500 раз, это понятно. Но как с обрезкой?

Comment: что именно "как с обрезкой"?

Comment: @Эникейщик мне нужно увеличить изображение, а потом обрезать, как вы сказали. По каким пропорциям мне обрезать, чтобы результат был, как в вопросе?

Comment: так обрезают не по пропорциям, а по размеру/координатам. Размер у вас, например, 1920х1080, воти обрезайте.

Comment: @Эникейщик тогда я не очень понимаю. Вот допустим, я увеличиваю с помощью `resize` изображение до нужного, потом обрезаю и в итоге я же получу изображение меньшего размера, чем нужно

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, в чем ваши непонятки. Не отрезайте слишком много, и не будет меньшего размера. Если у вас 2000, а нужно 1080, то нужно отрезать 920 и получится как раз 1080.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогло следующее решение, оно определяет горизонтальную либо вертикальную ориентацию изображения и в зависимости от этого обрезает изображения, а потом увеличивает до размеров переданных в `new_width` и `new_height`

```py
from PIL import Image


new_width, new_height = 1920, 1080
image = Image.open('test.png')
width, height = image.size
aspect_ratio = width / height
target_aspect_ratio = new_width / new_height
if aspect_ratio > target_aspect_ratio:
    crop_width = height * target_aspect_ratio
    left = (width - crop_width) / 2
    top = 0
    right = (width + crop_width) / 2
    bottom = height
else:
    crop_height = width / target_aspect_ratio
    left = 0
    top = (height - crop_height) / 2
    right = width
    bottom = (height + crop_height) / 2
image = image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
image = image.resize((new_width, new_height))
image.save('resizedimg.png')
```